# cx_freeze a python script including dropbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, dropbox, cx-freeze

I want to freeze a python script which is using dropbox to upload a file. I am using python 2.7 and windows 7. If I try just this example code:

```
import dropbox
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(<authtoken>)
client.put_file('FileName',"", overwrite=True)
```

I created an app with dropbox and generated a token which is explained on the dropbox homepage. The example works if I just use the python script. For future applications I want to freeze the script to use it on computers without python. 
If I execute the .exe file I get the error message below, I named the python script dropbox.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "dropbox.py", line 2, in <module>
File "H:\dropbox.py", line 3, in <module>
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient("authToken")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

**Solved: Do not use dropbox.py for your example scripts**
The error states that it can't find the client module, but how can fix this error?
My setup.py file is:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
base = None

executables = [
    cx_Freeze.Executable("dropbox.py", base = base),
    ]

build_exe_options = {"includes":[],
                     "include_files":[],
                     "excludes":[],
                     "packages":[]
                     }
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "script",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    version = "0.0",
    description = "A basic example",
    executables = executables)
```

I also tried to add in packages "dropbox" but it doesn't work.

I hope someone can help me. Maybe there is another way to upload a file to dropbox?

Cheers Max

Edit1:
Indeed it was a problem with the name of my example script. Though it still doesn't work. The new error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "mydropbox.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dropbox\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import client, rest, session
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dropbox\client.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .rest import ErrorResponse, RESTClient, params_to_urlencoded
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dropbox\rest.py", line 26, in <module>
    TRUSTED_CERT_FILE = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'trusted-certs.crt')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 950, in resource_filename
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 1638, in get_resource_filename
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip
```

I tried to solve the error with this site:

[enter link description here](http://mfctips.com/2013/05/03/dropbox-python-sdk-with-py2exe-causes-notimplementederror-resource_filename-only-supported-for-egg-not-zip/)

but doesn't work. Does anybody has a solution regarding my new error?

Comment: Have you called your script `dropbox.py`? If so, try calling it something else, like `dropbox-upload.py` - it might be finding your script instead of the dropbox package.

Comment: thx for the help, it changed the error to:
NotImplementedError: resource_filename() only supported for .egg, not .zip

Comment: I also found a thread where you solved the same problem, but I couldn't solve it? https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/19/dropbox-include

Comment: @ThomasK: I think it is a problem regarding the trusted-certs.crt, but how can I solve it?

Comment: @Max Dig into dropbox library, find out which line causes Error. You will surely solve it on yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem this way:

1) In your dropbox module location find the file "rest.py" (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\dropbox-2.2.0-py2.7.egg\dropbox - in my case)

2) Comment the string `TRUSTED_CERT_FILE = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'trusted-certs.crt')`

3) You can either write

`TRUSTED_CERT_FILE = 'trusted-certs.crt'` (I've used this way) or

`if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):`

`TRUSTED_CERT_FILE = 'trusted-certs.crt'`

`else:`

`TRUSTED_CERT_FILE = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'trusted-certs.crt')`

4) Remove all pyc files from dropbox directory and run the py file with your program

5) Rebuild your executable with cx_freeze

6) Copy trusted-certs.crt file from dropbox directory into library.zip/dropbox

7) Enjoy!